# How to read multiple json files

Tags: json, go

I am trying to read json data from multiple json files. I am not sure how I read each files and concatenate all results

There json files name are test1.json, test2.json test3.json..etc with the same data structure but I am having an issue read then all and my code seems to only show the last one. I have concatenated a string based on the file name but seems to not working for me.

```
type Book struct {
    Id    string `json: "id"`
    Title string `json: "title"`
}

func main() {
    fileIndex := 2 // three json files. All named test1.json, test2.json and test3.json

    var master []Book

    for i := 0; i <= fileIndex; i++ {
        fileName := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "test", fileIndex, ".json")

        // Open jsonFile
        jsonFile, err := os.Open(fileName)

        defer jsonFile.Close()

        byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
        fmt.Println(byteValue)
        var book []Book

        json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &book)
        fmt.Println(book) // all print shows the test3.json result 
    }
}
```

I need to be able to read all three json files and hoping to concatenate all results. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: better to concatenate unmarshaled json result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `fileIndex` while generating the filename instead of using `i` in the for loop.
The code after the changes would be :

```golang
type Book struct {
    Id    string `json: "id"`
    Title string `json: "title"`
}

func main() {
    fileIndex := 2 // three json files. All named test1.json, test2.json and test3.json

    var master []Book

    for i := 0; i <= fileIndex; i++ {
        fileName := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "test", i, ".json")

        // Open jsonFile
        jsonFile, err := os.Open(fileName)

        defer jsonFile.Close()

        byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
        fmt.Println(byteValue)
        var book []Book

        json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &book)
        fmt.Println(book)
    }
}
```

Also, you can do something like `master = append(master, book)` inside the for loop to finally get all JSON content in `master`